org-babel: How to Disable Code Evaluations on Export in Org Mode While Still Processing Header Arguments Like `:exports`?
I'm using Emacs Org mode and want to configure my setup so that code blocks are not evaluated during export. I have set org-export-use-babel to nil to do this. But this setting also disables header arguments like :exports, which I need.
How can I achieve this balance between disabling code evaluation but retaining the functionality of header argument processing? Are there specific configurations or best practices for this scenario?

org-export-use-babel (docs):
Switch controlling code evaluation and header processing during export.
When set to nil no code will be evaluated as part of the export
process and no header arguments will be obeyed.  Users who wish
to avoid evaluating code on export should use the header argument
:eval never-export.

Not really sure what you are asking: what do you mean "process certain header arguments"? Process them how?

@NickD Is the question now clear? I had used an LLM to rewrite the question to be more fluent, but it had dropped the crucial reference to org-export-use-babel. Sorry!

Doesn't the doc string of org-export-use-babel answer your question? It says: Users who wish to avoid evaluating code on export should use the header argument :eval never-export. You can set that on the whole file with a header-args property.

... and of course reset org-export-use-babel to t: you want the export processing, you just don't want to evaluate the code blocks.

@NickD Can I set org-export-use-babel per file instead?

You can (see File variables in the Emacs manual) but that won't work: if you set it to nil, you will block evaluation but also header-arg processing. So you can't set it "instead": the two have to work together.
